# Attaching file in embed from sqlite3 database

Tags: sqlite, discord.py, sqlite3-python

I would like to send an embed with a picture, originating from a sqlite3 database. I am correctly fetching the file but it won't display it in the embed.

```py
def init_embed(title, description, colour, picture):
    
    # Create a discord.File object from the image data
    file = discord.File(BytesIO(picture), filename='picture.png')

    # Name and description
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title,
                          description=description,
                          colour=colour)

    embed.set_image(url="attachment://oc_picture.png")  # Set the image using the discord.File object
   
    return embed
```

The embed is sent properly, the image is just not there for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image), you simply need to send in context the embed and the file in question with:

```py
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

This works like a charm!